# YII2 how to use pjax to submit a form without refresh the page

Tags: yii2, pjax

I use a `yii2` to create a website, trying to use a form to submit some data.
Can some body give me a example. Tell me how to use **pjax** to `submit` a form without reload the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an example of Yii2 Pjax submit form in this [link](http://blog.neattutorials.com/examples/pjax/web/site/form-submission)

---

**views\site\form-submission.php:**

```
<?php Pjax::begin(); ?>
    <?= Html::beginForm(['site/form-submission'], 'post', ['data-pjax' => '', 'class' => 'form-inline']); ?>
    <?= Html::input('text', 'string', Yii::$app->request->post('string'), ['class' => 'form-control']) ?>
    <?= Html::submitButton('Hash String', ['class' => 'btn btn-lg btn-primary', 'name' => 'hash-button']) ?>
    <?= Html::endForm() ?>
    <h3><?= $stringHash ?></h3>
<?php Pjax::end(); ?>
```

**controllers\SiteController.php:**

```
public function actionFormSubmission()
{
    $security = new Security();
    $string = Yii::$app->request->post('string');
    $stringHash = '';
    if (!is_null($string)) {
        $stringHash = $security->generatePasswordHash($string);
    }
    return $this->render('form-submission', [
        'stringHash' => $stringHash,
    ]);
}
```

Comment: What if I want to submit the form but my Pjax container is below it ?